# Ideals of $R = R_1 \oplus R_2 \oplus \dots \oplus R_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, direct-sum

I'm trying to show that if $A$ is an ideal of $R = R_1 \oplus R_2 \oplus \dots \oplus R_n$ then $A = A \cap R_1 \oplus A \cap R_2 \oplus \dots \oplus A \cap R_n$

I've been running around in my head nonstop on this one and can't seem to make any headway... can someone point me in the right direction?? Thanks!

Comment: Are your rings unital?

Comment: The direction $\supseteq$ is clear.

Comment: You have to be careful with notation like $A\cap R_1$. Strictly speaking it doesn't make sense (or, at best, is the empty set), so it's an abuse of notation and you should know what it actually means.

Comment: This seems like an edit of your [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2917401/29335). It would probably have been better to change that one rather than repost. This time, nobody will mind because there wasn't any feedback so to speak, but beware of reposting when comments/feedback already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $R_1 , \dots , R_n$ are unital with unity $e_i$ for each $i$ and that $R_i$ is notation for the copy of each ring in the sum, we have that the element $e = \sum_{i = 1}^ne_i$ verifies $er = r$ for all $r \in R$. Moreover, $e_i^2 = e_i$ and $e_ie_j = 0$ if $i \neq j$. Now,

$$
A = eA = e_1A + \dots + e_nA_n
$$

So we are left to see that $e_iA = R_i \cap A$ and that the sum is direct. If $a \in A \cap  R_i$, then

$$
a = ea = e_ia \in e_iA
$$

where here we use that $e_ja \in e_jR_i = e_je_iR_i = 0$ if $j \neq i$. Reciprocally, if $a \in e_iA$, then $a \in A$ because $A$ is an ideal and $a \in e_iA \subseteq e_iR = R_i$. Thus $A \cap R_i = e_iA$. Finally, we see that these ideals are direct summands: if $a_1 + \dots + a_n = 0$ with $a_i \in e_iA$, then for each $j$ we have that

$$
0 = e_j0 = e_j(a_1 + \dots+a_n) = e_ja_1 + \dots + e_ja_n = \\
= e_je_1a_1 + \dots + e_je_na_n = e_je_ja_j = a_j 
$$

and so we see that $a_j = 0$ for all $j$, which proves that the sum is direct.